# Quick question about open_basedir

Tags: open-basedir

On my server, I have following setting:

```
open_basedir    

    /home/
    :/usr/lib/php
    :/usr/local/lib/php
    :/tmp/
    :/usr/local/
    :/usr/bin
```

Now, I am little bit confused about ending **/** in the / home **/** setting, does that mean that all subfolders inside home have same rights? or does it mean that only home files can be accessed?

So, basically what is the main difference between:

/home/

and

/home

With example if possible

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/home/ means that only the /home folder is allowed
/home means that any folder that matches /home is allowed (examples : /home, /home2, /home_files and so on)